# Cursor flickers when trying to resize image in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I hope this is a simple question. I do the following:

1. In VS2010, I create a Windows Form Application
2. From the Toolbox, drag RichTextBox control to the form
3. Size the form and RichTextBox control large enough to display a small picture.
4. Run (start debugging).
5. Copy a small image from a web browser and paste to richtextbox (using ctrl-v).
6. Select the image in the richtextbox.  A resize frame is displayed with small boxes.

Now when I position the cursor over one of the small resizer boxes, the cursor flickers. I see glimpses of the resize arrow cursor but most the time it displays the I-beam cursor.   It does not steadily show the arrow cursors as it does when the a picture is pasted into WordPad and the cursor placed over the one of the small resize boxes.  Should resizing a picture in the RichTextBox behave the same as in WordPad?  How can I stop the cursor flicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this **hack** you will be able to resize the image without flickering, and with the correct `Arrows Cursors`.

**How**

First you will need to subclass the `RichTextBox` and override the method `WndProc`, so when the `RichTextBox` receives the message to change its `Cursor`, we will check if the image is select --- well, I don't really known if is an `Image`, but it is an `Object` and not `Text`.

If the `Image` is selected, we redirect the `message` to `DefWndProc` --- which is the Default Window Procedure.

**The code:**

```
public class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
{
    private const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR) 
        {
            if (SelectionType == RichTextBoxSelectionTypes.Object) 
            {
                DefWndProc(ref m);
                return;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great!  I wonder if there is a way to tell when the cursor is over the image and disable the change when it isn't.  Maybe that will get rid of the other flickering.

Comment: When you click at the `RichTextBox`, it will check what is below the mouse. Maybe we can find what `message` is sent to "known" if is an `Image`  or a `Text`. (one day I hope to discover it)

Comment: @Hal, I improved the code. I finally get rid of the flickering!

Comment: +1. Side note: I don't know why you consider your code a hack. It's common to subclass WinForms controls and override different methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2018 and this problem is still happening...

It is not the best, but I create a workaround. I believe that we can improve this code --- maybe in the future I do it myself.

---

You need to subclass `RichTextBox` and then add the following to force the `Cursor` to be what it should be.

Notice that the `Cursor` is either `Cross` for *Objects* like pictures OR `I-Beam` for texts.

---

How it works:

1. Every time that the `RichTextBox` requests a Cursor change (`SetCursor`), we intercept it and check if an Object is `Selected`.
2. If true, then change the cursor for `Cross`. If false, then change it to `I-Beam`.

---

```
class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
{
    private const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x20;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetCursor(IntPtr hCursor);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR) 
        {
            if (SelectionType == RichTextBoxSelectionTypes.Object) 
            {
                // Necessary to avoid recursive calls
                if (Cursor != Cursors.Cross) 
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                // Necessary to avoid recursive calls
                if (Cursor != Cursors.IBeam) 
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
                }
            }

            SetCursor(Cursor.Handle);
            return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That does get rid of cursor flicker.  But as you mentioned this shows a cross cursor at all times when an image is selected.  I am hoping for a solid solution that shows the appropriate resize cursor to be steadily shown when the cursor is over the resize adornment, else an arrow when over the image and the I-beam when not on the image.  This is the behavior in WordPad and the MFC Rich Edit Control.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following property

```
/// <summary>
/// The Lower property CreateParams is being used to reduce flicker
/// </summary>
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        const int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248216/how-to-smoothly-transition-a-panel-in-winforms/32248471#32248471).

Comment: That did reduce flickering - but now I don't see resize arrow cursors at all when the mouse hovers over the resize boxes.